# itext pdf generation is not working in executable jar file

Tags: java, javafx, itext, executable-jar

I have made one pdf generator using itext pdf 5.2.0. It properly worked on Netbeans but when I made the project as an executable jar file, the pdf is not generated. how to wrap libraries with jar files?? please guide me on what to do.

Comment: Actually, your question is all about creating executable jar of your project and execute it to generate PDF file. for additional information to get the answer quickly from the community, you have to add the relevant maven/gradle file

Comment: pack the itext jar into your pdf generator jar